# SharePoint client side people picker

Tags: jsom, people-picker

When I am creating a client side people picker,it is working fine when I am pasting the name or email ID on the textbox. But when i am writing in it, it won't work and no clues are coming for the users. Please help, the code is same as given everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..this is working code in my environment.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label id="Name">Employee Name<span class="error-msg">*</span>
    </label>
    <div id="txtName"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<siteurl>/_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<siteurl>/_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<siteurl>/_layouts/15/clientforms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<siteurl>/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<siteurl>/_layouts/15/autofill.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<siteurl>/_layouts/15/1033/sts_strings.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        initializePeoplePicker('txtName');
    });

    function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId, Users) {
        if (typeof(Users) == 'undefined') Users = null;
        // Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
        var schema = {};
        schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
        schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
        schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
        schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = false;
        schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
        schema['Width'] = '280px';
        this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, Users, schema);
    }
</script>
```